# how to identify the occurrence of first two characters of a number from a text file?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a text file that contains the names of people and their telephone numbers.

I want to identify the number of people with the telephone number beginning with 85.

The file looks like this :

```html
\`EMAIL, NAME, LAST_NAME, TEL, CITY
, Ivan, Abramov, 7776514, Moscow
, Alexey, Nikolaev, 1348520, Moscow
, Marina, Shapar, 1111110, Moscow
, Dmitriy, Vasilyev, 0000000, Kazan
, Ekaterina, Ilyina, , St.Petersburg
, Anastasiya, Grigoryan, 1928421, Ekaterinburg
, Andrey, Fedorov, 85212384, Minsk
, Alexey, Lisitsyn, 1239532, Tver
, Dariya, Abramova, 7163908, Moscow
, Alexandr, Evdokimov, 482, Volokolamsk
, Nataliya, Kostina, 9031433, Moscow
, Nikolay, Ermolin, 8539233, St.Petersburg
, , , , 
, Vladimir, Solovovo, 4758395, St.Petersburg
, Vladimir, Ivanov, 4827594, Novosibirsk
, Sergey, Nikolaev, 1294375, Sarov
, Ivan, Ivanov, 8532354, Kazan
, Konstantin, Semenov, 8532286, Moscow
, Grigoriy, Smirnov, 3249235, Kaliningrad
, Vasiliy, , 7123465, Moscow
, Alexandr, Lashko, 9548324, St.Petersburg
, sdfsdf, dwfef, 9994532, Rostov
, Oksana, Edger, 8548433, Kostroma
, Olga, Bogomolova, 8953253, Moscow
, Evgeniy, Strizh, 1123313, Krasnodar
, Valentina, Sergach, 12345567, St.Petersburg
, Polina, Volskaya, 1394542, Vladimir
, Fedor, Malinin, 9453223, Moscow
, Olga, Pahomova, 8543231, Moscow
, ffff, ffff, ffff, fffff
, Stepan, Bogdanov, 4564624, St.Petersburg
, Dmitriy, Smirnov, 9355r24, Kazan
, Valeria, Kolokolkina, 12O4352, St.Petersburg
, Ivan, Sobolev, 2350223, Kirov
, Kristina, Orlova, 1342349, Talnakh
, Alexandr, Ermolin, 2345234, Mozhaysk
, Ekaterina, Vasilevskaya, 9583573, Moscow
, Tatiana, Koroleva, 8674532, Vidnoe
, Elena, Moskvina, 7584294, Moscow
, , , 8954245, Moscow
, Mikhail, Sinev, 5964353, St.Petersburg
, NO_NAME, NO_NAME, 2856735, Kaliningrad
, Anastasiya, Boshich, 9654534, Omsk
, Svetlana, Kapustina, 9476353, Moscow
, Boris, Nikolaev, 9583583, Moscow
, Andrey, Mozgvin, 8537572, Krasnodar
, Oksana, Bogatyreva, 8743565, St.Petersburg
, Kseniya, Nosatenko, 1234194, Yaroslavl
, fwefwgwgwfds, sfewrfw, 9584356, Pskov
, Konstantin, Grigoriev, 1284575, Moscow
```

Furthermore, I used this code, but it does not work. it keeps giving me zero though it must be 7.

```py
f = open('task_file.txt' , 'r')
for line in f:
    if line.split(',')[3] != '':
        if line.split(',')[3][0:2] == '85' :
            a += 1
print(a)
f.close()
```

Comment: You are splitting by `,` but each entry is separated by both a comma AND a space. You may need to either trim before testing for `85` or test for `' 85'` on the first three characters.

Comment: @JNevill can you please clarify with writing the **code**?

Comment: Oh @CaptainCaveman Thanks! I didn't even see it. Will upvote :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to be snarky.

Comment: Your answer was better than my attempt anyway. It would have still failed since it was trimming only the `' 8'`. No snark taken :)

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('task_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    count = 0
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip().split()
        if line[3][0:2] == '85':
            count += 1
# output: 7
print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f = open('task_file.txt', 'r')
text = f.read() # read the contents of file object
f.close() # we stored the text, can close the file
text = text.replace(' ', '') # get rid of spaces
text_list = text.split(',') # get a list of strings
n = 0
for t in text_list:
    if t[:2] == '85':
        n += 1
print(n)
```

Comment: This works. Upvote. If you use 'with open', you don't have to close the file, and if you use strip().split() you can get rid of the replace() and split() lines. Strip will also get rid of instances of more than one consecutive space.

Comment: replace() will replace all instances, including any number of consecutive instances.

Comment: yes, that is true. I meant, what if there are two spaces side by side?

Comment: @CaptainCaveman it will replace any number of consecutive instances, including two spaces side-by-side.

Comment: Ah, I was incorrect! Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @CaptainCaveman Also, your answer to this has ```strip().split()``` which first takes away the leading and trailing spaces of the original string, and then splits the string based on the spaces, not commas.  It's behavior is not what you'd expect.  I don't have enough experience points to comment on your answer.

Comment: My answer works, I tested it. Try it out and let me know.

Comment: @CaptainCaveman I know it works.  You're just not delineating the data in a way that is intuitive to the dataset.  The dataset is comma separated.